# How to sort users in descendant order by the value of another table? ( rails )

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a users table, and an orders table. One user can have multiple orders.

Users table:

```
| id | username | email |
-------------------------
| .. | ....     | ..... |
-------------------------
```

Orders table:

```
| id | user_id | price |
------------------------
| .. | .....   | ....  |
------------------------
```

How can I sort users by number of orders in descendant order?

Now what I can think of is this:

```
@users = User.order('orders.count desc').all
```

But it doesn't seem correct. Can anyone help? thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use includes and references.

Comment: If I know the answer I will not post the question like this, thanks!

Comment: Sorry. you gotta use aggregate function. Will get back to you in an hour. im on phone now. lol. what DB are you using? Mysql and Postgress may have different syntax.

Comment: I use Mysql, thank you for your sincere support. I have found the answer, and I posted it below =))

Comment: Yeah. I marked it as answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you you guys! I just have found the answer from this website: http://chibicode.com/order-posts-by-comments-count-in-rails/

I add this code:

```
User.joins(:orders).group("users.id").order('count(orders.id) desc').all
```

And it works like magic. =))